# C++ template specialization - specialize only some methods, using default impl for the rest

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have a template like:

```
template <typename T>
class MyThing {
 public:
  static void Write(T value) { ... }
  static void Flush() { ... }
}
```

For a specific type, eg `bool`, I want to specialize the `Write` method without modifying the other methods.  Something like this...

```
// Specialize Write() behavior for <bool> ...
// This won't work. Mything<bool> no longer has a Flush() method!
template <>
class MyThing<bool> {
 public:
  static void Write(bool value) { ... }
}
```

How do I specialize just one of the methods in a template class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this turns out to be simple ...

All I need to do is to define the method in my .cc file:

```
template <>
void MyThing<bool>::Write(bool value) { ... }
```

And then declare it in my .h file:

```
template <>
void MyThing<bool>::Write(bool value);
```

It took me a while to figure this out, so I thought I'd post it.

Comment: Doesn't have to be static either. I never knew this was possible.

Comment: @Deduplicator - can you expand on your comment?  The explicit specialization is "visible" by being declared in the header file, no?  Ie, if I didn't add it to the header file, other code would use the default behavior by mistake.  Or are you implying something else too?